# CSS browser compatibility with styled-components

Tags: styled-components, css-in-js

I'm styling my Gatsby.js site with styled-components CSS-in-JS.

Is styled-components making my CSS compatible across browsers for me?

For example, say I'm styling a form. With traditional CSS I would do something like:

```css
button, input, select, textarea {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
       border-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

With styled-components, I'd like to do this:

```js
const Form = styled.form`
  button, input, select, textarea {
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
`
```

Can I omit these `-moz` or `-webkit` declarations and still end up with cross-browser compatible CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`styled-components` library has [opted for](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics) auto prefixing vendor styles, so you do not need to provide `-moz` or `-webkit extensions`.

The library will have it dealt for you. It is done with [`stylis`](https://stylis.js.org/) the parser that `styled-components` uses underneath. You can check their live preview to see which ones are added.